# RESTful NodeJs express server takes long to respond

Tags: node.js, express, restful-architecture

I have a RESTful NodeJS express server. When I make an API call the api retrieves data from a mongodb server hosted on modulus. While running the server from localhost sometimes it stops responding. When i query the database using robomongo it works. So I dont think there is a problem with the database connection to modulus. Is there any known issues regarding this ?

Comment: I think you are doing something very wrong somewhere in your code.

Comment: You're going to give some more details...

Comment: Like ? Can you suggest me some areas where an usual error occurs ? 
The same POST command works for the first time but the server isnt responding in the second time

Comment: Could you please post your code.